# Compare non-gaussian distributions and evaluate sampling process

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, paired-comparisons

I have a 150,000 datapoints (continuous values between 0 and 1) and I am running a process that averages groups of smaller samples based on some other data values and results in ~100,000 datapoints.  These datapoints are NOT gaussian and in fact some may have multiple peaks.

What I want to know/show is that the resulting sampled and averaged data distribution is the same or similar to the original data distribution.  Given averaging of smaller groups, I don't expect to see many (if any) ties.

Would a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test be a good way to show this?  Is there a better metric for demonstrating distribution similarity?